# Maven Always Compiles All The Source Files Under WSL2 Ubuntu Distro

Tags: maven, ubuntu, wsl-2

Under normal circumstances in Linux or Windows, Maven will only compile recently changed (incremental compilation) Java sources in the project. However, under Windows WSL2 (Ubuntu distro), all the sources are compiled every time `mvn compile` is executed. What do I need to fix to make Maven compiles only the more recent sources than the classes? Thank you

Comment: Is there declared [`<useIncrementalCompilation>false`](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-compiler-plugin/compile-mojo.html#useIncrementalCompilation) somewhere?

Comment: can't see it anywhere. The same project compiles different in 2 different environment

Comment: Have you checked [`help:effective-pom`](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-help-plugin/effective-pom-mojo.html)? Profiles, for instance, can be activated by [`<jdk>` or `<os>`](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-profiles.html).

Comment: good points. let me check it again later. it is getting late here

Comment: check and nothing unusual. just a plain `pom.xml`

Comment: The [`[Abstract]CompilerMojo`](https://github.com/apache/maven-compiler-plugin/blob/master/src/main/java/org/apache/maven/plugin/compiler/CompilerMojo.java) uses [org.codehaus.plexus.compiler.util.scan.SourceInclusionScanner](https://codehaus-plexus.github.io/plexus-compiler/plexus-compiler-api/apidocs/index.html?org/codehaus/plexus/compiler/util/scan/SourceInclusionScanner.html) but the description there is, well, not existent and I couldn't find its source so far to see how the sources are selected or not.

Comment: False alarm. I found out it has nothing to do with maven nor WSL2. It is the hyperactive files scanner that caused the problem. Thanks @GeroldBroser